# CFG for a = b and c = d (length)

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory, context-free-language, automata-theory

I know how to construct the context-free grammars for strings that have same counts of `a` and `b`, or have the same counts of `c` and `d`:

```
S → ε             S → ε
S → SASBS         S → SCSDS
S → SBSAS         S → SDSCS
A → a             C → c
B → b             D → d
```

But, I don't know how to create a grammar for strings where the counts of `a` and `b` are the same, and the counts of `c` and `d` are the same. My attempts fail for strings like `cadbdabc` where the pairings are between each other (ex: `c, <a>, d, <b>`). So, I would appreciate if someone could help out on this.

Comment: Do you mean, all four counts are the same? That's not context-free

Comment: @rici - No, number a's should be equal to b's, and a number of c's should be equal to d's regardless of the order. So, "caabdb" would be a string in the language (2 a's = 2 b's, and 1 c = 1 d).

Comment: @Rahul Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

The language you are trying to recognise is not context-free, so you're not going to be able to construct a context-free grammar for it.

To see that, remember that the language **a<sup>n</sup>c<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>d<sup>m</sup>** is not context-free. (You can easily prove that using the pumping lemma; in fact, it's one of the classic examples. Take a string where both **m** and **n** are greater than the pumping constant **p**; any substring *uvx* whose length is no greater than **p** can contain at most two different symbols with two different repetition counts; so replacing *u* and *x* with the empty string -- pumping 0 repetitions -- must make one of the equalities false.)

Now, let ***L*** be your language, and consider the intersection ***L* ∩ a*c*b*d***. The intersection of a context-free language and a regular language is [guaranteed to be context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure), and **a*c*b*d*** is obviously regular. So if ***L*** were context-free, then ***L* ∩ a*c*b*d*** would be context-free. But ***L* ∩ a*c*b*d*** is precisely the language **a<sup>n</sup>c<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>d<sup>m</sup>**, which is not context-free; a contradiction. Thus, ***L*** cannot be context-free.